# cut by interval and aggregate over one month in R

Tags: r, posix, aggregate, cut

I have the given data - all bike trips that started from a particular station over the month of October 2013.  I'd like to count the amount of trips that occurred within ten-minute time intervals.  There should be a total of 144 rows with a sum of all of the trips that occurred within that interval for the entire month.  How would one cut the data.frame and then aggregate by interval (so that trips occurring between 00:00:01 and 00:10:00 are counted in the second row, between 00:10:01 and 00:20:00 are counted in the third row, and so on...)?

```
head(one.station)
    tripduration           starttime            stoptime start.station.id start.station.name
59           803 2013-10-01 00:11:49 2013-10-01 00:25:12              521    8 Ave & W 31 St
208          445 2013-10-01 00:40:05 2013-10-01 00:47:30              521    8 Ave & W 31 St
359          643 2013-10-01 01:25:57 2013-10-01 01:36:40              521    8 Ave & W 31 St
635          388 2013-10-01 05:30:30 2013-10-01 05:36:58              521    8 Ave & W 31 St
661          314 2013-10-01 05:38:00 2013-10-01 05:43:14              521    8 Ave & W 31 St
768          477 2013-10-01 05:54:49 2013-10-01 06:02:46              521    8 Ave & W 31 St
    start.station.latitude start.station.longitude end.station.id   end.station.name
59                40.75045               -73.99481           2003    1 Ave & E 18 St
208               40.75045               -73.99481            505    6 Ave & W 33 St
359               40.75045               -73.99481            508   W 46 St & 11 Ave
635               40.75045               -73.99481            459   W 20 St & 11 Ave
661               40.75045               -73.99481            462   W 22 St & 10 Ave
768               40.75045               -73.99481            457 Broadway & W 58 St
    end.station.latitude end.station.longitude bikeid   usertype birth.year gender
59              40.73416             -73.98024  15139 Subscriber       1985      1
208             40.74901             -73.98848  20538 Subscriber       1990      2
359             40.76341             -73.99667  19935   Customer        \\N      0
635             40.74674             -74.00776  14781 Subscriber       1955      1
661             40.74692             -74.00452  17976 Subscriber       1982      1
768             40.76695             -73.98169  19022 Subscriber       1973      1
```

So that the output looks like this

```
 
output
  interval total_trips
1 00:00:00           0
2 00:10:00           1
3 00:20:00           2
4 00:30:00           3
5 00:40:00           4
```

Comment: Look at the cut function. You can use it to tag each row with an interval and then extract counts by table or some similar mechanism.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how this could work on the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is using only start time:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
tripduration <- floor(runif(6) * 1000)
start_times <- as.POSIXlt(
  c("2013-10-01 00:11:49"
  ,"2013-10-01 00:40:05"
  ,"2013-10-01 01:25:57"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:30:30"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:38:00"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:54:49")
)
time_bucket <- start_times - minutes(minute(start_times) %% 10) - seconds(second(start_times))
df <- data.frame(tripduration, start_times, time_bucket)
summarized <- df %>%
  group_by(time_bucket) %>%
  summarize(trip_count = n())
summarized <- as.data.frame(summarized)
out_buckets <- data.frame(out_buckets = seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-10-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2013-10-01 06:0:00"), by = 600))
out <- left_join(out_buckets, summarized, by = c("out_buckets" = "time_bucket"))
out$trip_count[is.na(out$trip_count)] <- 0
out

               out_buckets trip_count
1  2013-10-01 00:00:00          0
2  2013-10-01 00:10:00          1
3  2013-10-01 00:20:00          0
4  2013-10-01 00:30:00          0
5  2013-10-01 00:40:00          1
6  2013-10-01 00:50:00          0
7  2013-10-01 01:00:00          0
8  2013-10-01 01:10:00          0
9  2013-10-01 01:20:00          1
10 2013-10-01 01:30:00          0
11 2013-10-01 01:40:00          0
12 2013-10-01 01:50:00          0
13 2013-10-01 02:00:00          0
14 2013-10-01 02:10:00          0
15 2013-10-01 02:20:00          0
16 2013-10-01 02:30:00          0
17 2013-10-01 02:40:00          0
18 2013-10-01 02:50:00          0
19 2013-10-01 03:00:00          0
20 2013-10-01 03:10:00          0
21 2013-10-01 03:20:00          0
22 2013-10-01 03:30:00          0
23 2013-10-01 03:40:00          0
24 2013-10-01 03:50:00          0
25 2013-10-01 04:00:00          0
26 2013-10-01 04:10:00          0
27 2013-10-01 04:20:00          0
28 2013-10-01 04:30:00          0
29 2013-10-01 04:40:00          0
30 2013-10-01 04:50:00          0
31 2013-10-01 05:00:00          0
32 2013-10-01 05:10:00          0
33 2013-10-01 05:20:00          0
34 2013-10-01 05:30:00          2
35 2013-10-01 05:40:00          0
36 2013-10-01 05:50:00          1
37 2013-10-01 06:00:00          0
```

Comment: This is very helpful!  Which part of the code should I modify, if, for example, my start.times will span over one month?

Comment: The sequence bit is what you change to get a different window of buckets. So for example:
`out_buckets <- data.frame(out_buckets = seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-10-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2013-10-01 06:0:00"), by = 600))` becomes `out_buckets <- data.frame(out_buckets = seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-10-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2013-11-01 00:0:00"), by = 600))`

Answer (score 1):

The [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) library can provide one solution. It has a nice function for interval overlap logic. The below uses `lapply` to loop through the intervals provided in the data then buckets them accordingly.

```
library(lubridate)

start_times <- as.POSIXlt(
  c("2013-10-01 00:11:49"
  ,"2013-10-01 00:40:05"
  ,"2013-10-01 01:25:57"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:30:30"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:38:00"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:54:49")
)

stop_times <- as.POSIXlt(
  c("2013-10-01 00:25:12"
  ,"2013-10-01 00:47:30"
  ,"2013-10-01 01:36:40"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:36:58"
  ,"2013-10-01 05:43:14"
  ,"2013-10-01 06:02:46")
)

start_bucket <- seq(as.POSIXct("2013-10-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2013-10-01 06:0:00"), by = 600)
end_bucket <- start_bucket + 600
bucket_interval <- interval(start_bucket, end_bucket)
data_interval <- interval(start_times, stop_times)

int_list <- lapply(data_interval, function(x) ifelse(int_overlaps(x, bucket_interval),1,0))
rides_per_bucket <- rowSums(do.call(cbind, int_list))
out_df <- data.frame(bucket_interval, rides_per_bucket)
out_df
                                    bucket_interval rides_per_bucket
1  2013-10-01 00:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 00:10:00 PDT                0
2  2013-10-01 00:10:00 PDT--2013-10-01 00:20:00 PDT                1
3  2013-10-01 00:20:00 PDT--2013-10-01 00:30:00 PDT                1
4  2013-10-01 00:30:00 PDT--2013-10-01 00:40:00 PDT                0
5  2013-10-01 00:40:00 PDT--2013-10-01 00:50:00 PDT                1
6  2013-10-01 00:50:00 PDT--2013-10-01 01:00:00 PDT                0
7  2013-10-01 01:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 01:10:00 PDT                0
8  2013-10-01 01:10:00 PDT--2013-10-01 01:20:00 PDT                0
9  2013-10-01 01:20:00 PDT--2013-10-01 01:30:00 PDT                1
10 2013-10-01 01:30:00 PDT--2013-10-01 01:40:00 PDT                1
11 2013-10-01 01:40:00 PDT--2013-10-01 01:50:00 PDT                0
12 2013-10-01 01:50:00 PDT--2013-10-01 02:00:00 PDT                0
13 2013-10-01 02:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 02:10:00 PDT                0
14 2013-10-01 02:10:00 PDT--2013-10-01 02:20:00 PDT                0
15 2013-10-01 02:20:00 PDT--2013-10-01 02:30:00 PDT                0
16 2013-10-01 02:30:00 PDT--2013-10-01 02:40:00 PDT                0
17 2013-10-01 02:40:00 PDT--2013-10-01 02:50:00 PDT                0
18 2013-10-01 02:50:00 PDT--2013-10-01 03:00:00 PDT                0
19 2013-10-01 03:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 03:10:00 PDT                0
20 2013-10-01 03:10:00 PDT--2013-10-01 03:20:00 PDT                0
21 2013-10-01 03:20:00 PDT--2013-10-01 03:30:00 PDT                0
22 2013-10-01 03:30:00 PDT--2013-10-01 03:40:00 PDT                0
23 2013-10-01 03:40:00 PDT--2013-10-01 03:50:00 PDT                0
24 2013-10-01 03:50:00 PDT--2013-10-01 04:00:00 PDT                0
25 2013-10-01 04:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 04:10:00 PDT                0
26 2013-10-01 04:10:00 PDT--2013-10-01 04:20:00 PDT                0
27 2013-10-01 04:20:00 PDT--2013-10-01 04:30:00 PDT                0
28 2013-10-01 04:30:00 PDT--2013-10-01 04:40:00 PDT                0
29 2013-10-01 04:40:00 PDT--2013-10-01 04:50:00 PDT                0
30 2013-10-01 04:50:00 PDT--2013-10-01 05:00:00 PDT                0
31 2013-10-01 05:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 05:10:00 PDT                0
32 2013-10-01 05:10:00 PDT--2013-10-01 05:20:00 PDT                0
33 2013-10-01 05:20:00 PDT--2013-10-01 05:30:00 PDT                0
34 2013-10-01 05:30:00 PDT--2013-10-01 05:40:00 PDT                2
35 2013-10-01 05:40:00 PDT--2013-10-01 05:50:00 PDT                1
36 2013-10-01 05:50:00 PDT--2013-10-01 06:00:00 PDT                1
37 2013-10-01 06:00:00 PDT--2013-10-01 06:10:00 PDT                1
```

Comment: thank you! the only thing is that the `stoptime` is not important.  Is there a way to modify the code so that only start times are counted?

Comment: That is, in the output shown above, there should only be six total under `rides_per_bucket`

Comment: Thank you, also - in the end the date is not needed - all that is needed is 10 minute intervals from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00 and the counts.  This will be applied to 30 days of data